# Netbeans and compile errors

Tags: java, netbeans

I am putting together a new dev machine, Mac.

My old dev machine runs `Netbeans 6.8`. I have a file with a variable called enum. I get a warning saying :

> *enum is a keyword and can not be used as an identifier*

I am using `JDK 1.4.2` for this project.

My new machine another Mac, have installed `Netbeans 7.0`. Same nbproject, same file, I get an error instead of the warning and I can not find a way around this.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Thanks
Reza

For what is worth, the source is

```
 // make sure eager jars are up-to-date
  for (Enumeration enum = entry.getDescriptor().getResources().eagerJars();          
              enum.hasMoreElements();) {
                Reference jarRef = (Reference) enum.nextElement();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what I was NOT doing in the new version what I was not setting the project's setting for source/binary format to 1.4. It was defaulting to 1.6 even though I had set the Java platform to 1.4

Now the errors are turned into warnings.

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rename that identifier. The [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is a keyword and `enum` type is introduce in `Java 1.5`.

Comment: I understand that this fixes the problem, the project settings are equal, I am trying to find out why the one netbeans generates a warning and the new one generates an error. That is what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**
You are getting this error because the Java installed on your Mac may be version 1.5 or higher.  This means the issue is not with the **NetBeans IDE** but it is because of the version of the Java Development Kit [JDK] which is installed on the system.

**Solution:**
To make your program work out of the box without updating any code you have to follow the following steps;

1. Right click on the project name in the **Projects** panel, and click the **Properties** option in the context menu. This will display the **Project Properties** dialog box with the **Sources** node in the **Categories** tree view selected.
2. Keeping the **Sources** node selected, go to the **Source/Binary Format** combo box and ensure that `JDK 1.4` is selected in that combo box, click the **Ok** button to save these settings.
3. These settings will ensure that you can build the project with `JDK 1.4` source compatibility and then the `enum` identifier will not be taken as keyword.

**Recommedation:**
It is recommended to change the usage of `enum` word as identifier like local variable, to some other word like enum1, if you want to keep the source code compatible with the new JDK versions starting from JDK1.5 and onwards.  The `enum` word has been added to the keywords in Java Language from JDK1.5 hence it will be reported as error when you compile your code with JDK1.5 source compatibility.

Comment: I understand the fix and the reason for the error. What I am trying to understand is why one netbeans installation generates a warning for this and one generates an error.